# how to combine two arrays?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have two arrays like this

first array

```
Array
(
    [0228] => Array
        (
            [name] => ''
            [address] => ''
        )

    [0275] => Array
        (
            [name] => ''
            [address] => ''
        )
)
```

second array

```
Array
(
    [0228] => Array
        (
            [start_date] => ''
            [payment] => ''
        )

    [0275] => Array
        (
            [start_date] => ''
            [payment] => ''
        )
)
```

i want to combine these two by matching array keys and get out put like

```
Array
(
    [0228] => Array
        (
            [name] => ''
            [address] => ''
            [start_date] => ''
            [payment] => ''
        )

    [0275] => Array
        (
            [name] => ''
            [address] => ''
            [start_date] => ''
            [payment] => ''
        )
)
```

how to do this ? is there any built in function in php for these kind of array combine?

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

There are more array functions here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 6):

use `array_merge_recursive` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php